# javascript does not splice all the element of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

http://jsfiddle.net/4wKuj/8/

```
  var myarr=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");       
  console.log(myarr);
  for (var i=0; i<myarr.length; i++) {
    myarr.splice(i,1);
  }
  console.log(myarr);
```

Note: in the real implementation I am not trying to empty the array so plz do not suggest other way of emptying an array.

Why I still see  "volvo" in the console log ?

Should not it be removed either , same as other ?

Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What it does :

- first iteration, `i=0`, removes `"Saab"`, => array is `["Volvo","BMW"]`
- second iteration, `i=1`, removes `"BMW"` because this is what you have at index `1`

Answer (score 1):

After the first splice:

```
i = 1
myarr = ["Volvo", "BMW"]
```

So it will remove `"BMW"`. After the second splice:

```
i = 2
myarr = ["Volvo"]
```

And the loop will not continue. Better do it like this:

```
while (myarr.length > 1) {
    myarr.splice(0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before loop, your array looks like

> ["Saab","Volvo","BMW"]

after first iteration of loop you delete first element of array, and now array looks like

> ["Volvo","BMW"]

during second iteration your "i" variable has '1' (one) value that corresponds to second element of array, in other words you say:

delete in ["Volvo","BMW"] array element with index '1'

Answer (score 0):

If you remove an item from the array, you also need to adjust the index value, f.ex:

```
var myarr=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW");       
for (var i=0; i<myarr.length; i++) {
  myarr.splice(i--,1);
}
```

Tip: If you are using a loop remove items from an array based on it’s value, you can use other methods, f.ex [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
myarr = myarr.filter(function(val) {
    return val !== 'Volvo'
});
```

`Array.indexOf` also comes to mind.